# How to prevent Widget from echoing to wrong position in DOM

Tags: widgets, page-template

I am following [this tutorial](https://slicejack.com/create-fully-custom-wordpress-mega-menu-no-plugins-attached/) to create a mega menu in Wordpress. It utilizes widgets to house the submenu content. My issue is when echoing the widget, it renders outside of its parent in the DOM.

Here's my current code:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <?php
        $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
        if ( isset( $locations[ 'mega_menu' ] ) ) {
            $menu = get_term( $locations[ 'mega_menu' ], 'nav_menu' );
            if ( $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->name ) ) {
                foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo "<a href=\"{$item->url}\">{$item->title}</a>";
                    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'mega-menu-widget-area-' . $item->ID ) ) {
                        echo "<div id=\"mega-menu-{$item->ID}\" class=\"mega-menu\">";
                            dynamic_sidebar( 'mega-menu-widget-area-' . $item->ID );
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                echo "</li>";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

The widget content is not rendering as a child of the `<div>`, but rather it is rendering as a sibling to its parent `<li>`.

Current DOM output:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="http://water-wp/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://water-wp/solutions/">Solutions</a>
  </li>

  <!-- Should not be a list item, but rather a child div of the previous list item -->
  <li id="text-2" class="widget widget_text">
    <h2 class="widgettitle">Heading</h2>
        <div class="textwidget">hnjsf skhdfj sdf</div>
  </li>
  <div id="mega-menu-32" class="mega-menu"> 1</div>      
</ul>
```

Desired DOM output:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="http://water-wp/">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="http://water-wp/solutions/">Solutions</a>

    <div id="mega-menu-32" class="mega-menu">
      <h2 class="widgettitle">Heading</h2>
      <div class="textwidget">hnjsf skhdfj sdf</div>
    </div>       
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

dynamic_sidebar will output the sidebar when it is called. Try using it with buffering and store into a variable as below:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <?php
        $locations = get_nav_menu_locations();
        if ( isset( $locations[ 'mega_menu' ] ) ) {
            $menu = get_term( $locations[ 'mega_menu' ], 'nav_menu' );
            if ( $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu->name ) ) {
                foreach ( $items as $item ) {
                    echo "<li>";
                    echo "<a href=\"{$item->url}\">{$item->title}</a>";
                    ob_start();
                    dynamic_sidebar('mega-menu-widget-area-' . $item->ID);
                    $sidebar = ob_get_contents();
                    ob_end_clean();
                    if ( is_active_sidebar( 'mega-menu-widget-area-' . $item->ID ) ) {
                        echo "<div id=\"mega-menu-{$item->ID}\" class=\"mega-menu\">";
                            echo $sidebar;
                        echo "</div>";
                    }
                echo "</li>";
                }
            }
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I tried this, but the result is the same.